# Problem with sending an email

Tags: android, android-intent

I wrote the following code for sending E-Mail,

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                     sendIntent.setType("plain/text");
                     sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,emailAddress);
                     sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,emailSubject);
                     sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,emailBody);
                     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,
                     "Choose email Application"));
```

But when the EMail application opens I have "To", "Subject", and "Content" fields empty. 
What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

The emailAddress variable has to be a String Array of emails.

Check emailSubject and emailBody are of type String. You can also try sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
sendIntent.setType("plain/text");
```

should be

```
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
```

but in fact better is

```
sendIntent.setType( "message/rfc822" );
```